# Parallel Execution of all cucumber scenarios in multiple browsers applicable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cross-browser, cucumber-java

I am trying to achieve Parallel execution of all scenarios run in all the browsers.

High level Set Up:
Feature Files: I use multiple tags with same scenario like below

@chrome @firefox
Scenario :
Given
When
Then

App Hooks:
@Before (@chrome)
--Initialize Chrome Browser

@Before (@firefox)
--Initialize firefox Browser

Test Runner:
tags="@chrome or @firefox"

While running in parallel, getting error 500.

Solution I see:

1. Have Multiple runner files
2. Or Have Multiple feature files.

Please let me know for any solutions.

Solution I See is having multiple runner/multiple feature files. Any other solutions